# Use "if statement" and psutil to detect internet disconnection of a game and then reconnect

Tags: python, networking, psutil

I am a beginner level, so please bear with me if I make rookie mistake.

Basically what I am trying to achieve here is:

1. Using psutil to extract current network usage
2. If the network usage=0, that means my game is disconnected from server
3. If above happens, python will run a mouse-clicking script to restart my game

Note that, I only leave my game on, so if there is any network usage, it's always only from the game, thus if no network usage, that means game is disconnected.

step 3 I have tested individually, it works, but step 1 and 2, I just can't figure out where it goes wrong. It tells me 'syntax error', but I copy paste the psutil part same as other example I found on internet.

```
import psutil

psutil.net_io_counters()

if psutil.net_io_counters()=0

import os

os.startfile(r"C:\Users\14168\Desktop\WOWScript\Reconnection.ahk")
```

Comment: The end of your `if` statement is missing a colon and a single equal sign is an assignment operator, not a comparison operator (use double equals `==` instead). So the line should look like `if psutil.net_io_counters()==0:`. The things that execute if the statement is true need to be indented

Comment: Even if you only leave your game on, your OS can also be trying to use the network. Which means that your game might not be connected but the network utilisation might be non-zero. So this might not be a robust solution in the first place?

Comment: Hi, thank you for pointing out my syntax error, it did work; just a follow up, if i want to use "<" or ">" it gave me error TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'snetio' and 'int', so what should I do? Or I can only use "=="?

Comment: I looked at my task manager, and the game always at least maintain 0.1Mbps, everything else is 0. So I could just set the condition to if network usage<0.1mbps? but how should I write 0.1 mbps so that it knows what i mean, I assume <0.1mbps will not be recognized

Comment: Terminology note: `if` is not a function, it is part of an if statement (or other various expressions, like a conditional expression or a list comprehension etc...)